# C# Integer limits for Scriptable Objects

Tags: unity, c#

I am experimenting with `Scriptable Objects` in Unity. In the following example how can I limit the range of accepted values?

```
public class AScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
   public uint damage;
}
```

Since it's a `uint` the lowest value is `0` but how can I limit the max value to 500 for example? Can I use `if` statements?

Comment: Have you looked into using the [Range attribute](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RangeAttribute.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to set it both via editor and script and have it always clamp the value you can write it this way

```
public class AScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    private const int MyMaxValue = 500;
    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0, MyMaxValue)]
    private uint m_damage;

    public uint damage
    {
        get
        {
            return m_damage;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= MyMaxValue)
                value = MyMaxValue;
            m_damage = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note it won't allow you to have MyMaxValue > int.MaxValue because the range attribute only takes in an int, and not a uint

Comment: Hmm, pretty accurate to what I wanted to do. In my case I use `[System.Serializable]` before `public class AScriptableObject : ScriptableObject`. Do I need to use `[SerializeField]` in front of a `private uint` as well?

Comment: Yes, System.Serializable will tell unity that your class can be serialized, then the SerializeField tells unity to serialize the private field

Answer (score 2):

```
[Range(0,500)] public uint damage;
```

Should do the trick. This will be show as a slider in the inspector that goes from 0 to 500.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this is what the OP wants. It limits the value in the editor, but not when set through a script while the game is running.

Comment: Well the OP did not specify his use case. Either way the two answers given cover both cases

Comment: @UriPopov My bad, I thought that leaving it "in general" it would be clear that I meant : in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity's MathF.Clamp() method.
If you use this method each time you give a value to your integer, it resctricts the value between your min and max values.

For example: if you take a 400 value and use Clamp() method like this;

Mathf.Clamp(400, 0, 300); it returns 300.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Comment: When you want to do something "each time you give a value to your variable", the C# way to do this properly is by declaring the variable `private` and exposing it through a public [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) which handles this.